# When Jews started to believe in reincarnation?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, death, reincarnation

I found that (at least some of) modern Judaism partisans believe in reincarnation.

I want to know what is the first Judaism book explicitly and unambiguously showing belief in reincarnation and when this book was written or published (I am interested in its time of publication accordingly both Judaism religion and accordingly the mainline modern science).

Comment: @RobertColumbia Not a dupe. I think. This question requires rigorous answers. The other one accepts data not accepted by mainstream science such as an the Zohar and Bahir preceding the 10th century.

Comment: ZOHAR PARASHAT PINCHAS